# Weapon used by one of the Ultra-Robots

Tags: samurai-jack

In episode 18 Jack tracks down a troup of robot assassins commisioned by Aku to lure Jack out with random acts of violence, then kill him. Each robot is armed with different weapons- one in particular ejects a length of black cable that explodes shortly after landing on the ground.

Was this something Genndy and the writers thought up, or is it based on a weapon designed/conceived elsewhere?

[image]

Comment: Couldn't resist editing. Still on strike though.

Comment: *shakes head* @Richard

Answer (score 3):

This sounds very similar to the [Python Minefield Breaching System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_Minefield_Breaching_System) used by the British army, basically a cable filled with explosives that is fired from either a hand-held or machine-mounted launcher which then detonates in a long line.

The US Army uses a similar piece of kit called a [Mine-Clearing Line Charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mine-clearing_line_charge) (or MicLic for short)

Answer (score -1):

This specific weapon unlike the others does not seem to exist outside of Samurai Jack. I've done a lot of research around many types of weapon that could be related (rope,wire,string,exploding) to name a few.

The only real mention to wire weapons anywhere is the Garrote and it's many other names.

The wire weapon looks to be similar to a line of explosive gun powder so I went down the route of explosive weapons.

I then found this the [Bangalore Torpedo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bangalore_torpedo), now this is actually a charge placed in several connected tubes which is then used to remove obstacles at a distance and keep the detonator out of harms way. The way it lies on the ground and it's appearance are the most similar things I've found to the wire weapon used by the ultra bot.

As for exploding rope weapons, I found [Bolas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolas) whilst not inherently similar they could have aided in inspiration for an exploding rope/wire weapon.

Comment: [Detcord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detonating_cord)?